# How can I extract tags from a MP4 file with MP4Box or mediainfo on the command line

Tags: command-line, video, mp4, mp4box, media-info

I want to extract tag information like title, author, encoded date, tagged date and so on from several video, audio and subtitle tracks in .mp4 files (for later use in mkvmerge). I need the extracted information in a text or xml file and searching for the command line parameters. I know the [MP4Box docu](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/mp4box-documentation)/[mediainfo docu](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en/Support/FAQ), but they are not very helpful. If you have experience in this, please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- With MediaInfo:

  ```
  mediainfo --Output=XML input.mp4
  ```
- With MP4Box – this won't give you XML though and generally seems hard to parse:

  ```
  mp4box input.mp4 -info
  ```
- You can get more detailed output in XML with:

  ```
  mp4box input.mp4 -diso
  ```

  That would create a file called `input_info.xml`. This will be too much information for your use case though, I guess.